# Excel: Can I use one slicer to create an OR filter for two columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

See included screenshot.
I've got two of the 'same' columns, "Organisatie". The content of the table is the status (color) of a message between those two organisations. The table is meant to serve as an easily accessible overview of the status of all these messages between two organisations. Therefore, it should be possible to filter on organisation, since it's a rather long table. However, a slicer only allows me to filter for one column of organisations (party A), which is either the delivering or receiving party of the message. The counterpart (party B), being the other receiving or delivering party, is not included in the slicer. I could circumvent this problem by creating new rows for party B, but this is not the clean solution I'd like. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt4DY.png).
While pivot tables might have this functionality, I fail to get the color-coded bi-organisational overview I get with a regular table.

Additional information on the table: The first column is the type of message, the second is party A (an organization), the third is the message status for party A (can it either receive/send message), followed by the direction of the message and then mirrored: can party B receive/send message, then the name of the organization, and a comments column.

Comment: I don't think it's possible...